# Pandas query function with subexpressions that don't include a column name

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble with the pandas query function, where subexpressions don't include any of the frame's columns. I'd expect the following to give `[True, False]`, but in fact it responds `[False, True]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'col1':[1,0]} )

col1
0     1
1     0

external_var = 'yes'
df.eval( '(@external_var == "yes") == col1' )

0     False
1     True
```

The problem doesn't seem to relate to the use of `external_var`, because

`df.eval( '("yes" == "yes") == col1' )` 
gives the same unexpected result.

**context**

My use case is writing a system to assign points to a table of items, according to rules that can be written by non-programmers. The rules will depend on external event metadata (hence the `external_var` comparison), comparing this with columns in the frame. The query function seems ideal for this, but it doesn't seem to behave as expected. I tried reading source, but got lost somewhere in the `PandasExprVisitor` class.

One workaround I considered was to just assign each piece of external data to a column, but this seems to break down when the metadata itself includes lists.

These tests were run in jupyter using Pandas 0.16.2 and numexpr 2.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bug ([GH11044](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11044)) and maybe will be corrected in the Next Major Release milestone.

```
In [9]: df.eval( '("yes" == "yes")')
Out[9]: False
```

Comment: Thanks for that @jezrael. My expressions are not consisting of only scalar values, as I realise that this wouldn't make sense when trying to select a set of rows. Such queries, such as `1==1` give a `keyError` for `True`, which is understandable.

But I recognise that my expressions contain sub-expressions that consist of only scalar values. Do the documented rules apply to sub-expressions as well then? The code does run, but the result isn't correct.

Comment: While I agree that they should be equivalent, they're not: the result is different. I wrote this on your bug report and they agreed it's a bug now. Thank you very much for reporting it - if you update the answer that it's a bug, I'll accept it!

Comment: Ok, I updated answer. I think nobody use `df.eval` this way. I like pandas and still is better and better.